# How to obfuscate a url in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7, obfuscation, drupal-modules

http://example.com/mypagename

How do we hash or obfuscate this in drupal to be come something like:

http://example.com/ASarSADT%asd

Basically we don't want to reveal the /mypagename

Is there a module/setting for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If changing the alias with [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module doesn't work for you, you can do that with a ReWrite Rule in .htaccess and specify the obfuscate url yourself.

Comment: Thanks. We may do a combo of those, as we want the url hash to be unique (non copy and paste for everyone). We are also going to utilize CAS in order to force traffic to those pages to be logged authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Pathauto module, there is a [[random:hash:?]](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/256551/what-is-the-token-for-randomhash) token that should make for a viable obfuscation strategy.